# How can i configure attribute based routing on startup file instead of using attribute on controller action in asp.net core mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-routing

```
[Route("name/{code?}")]
public IActionResult Index(string Code)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { code = Code });
}
```

How can I configure this Route on Startup file Configure method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following code:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "Demo",
                pattern: "name/{code?}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        });
```